# Pandas Dataframe: How to fillna object types with one of value in the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example,I have a df.

```
data = {'product': ['coca', np.nan, 'pepsi', 'pepsi', 'orange',], 
    'price': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70,],
    'company':[np.nan,'coca-cola',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

OUT:

```
 company  price product
0        NaN     25    coca
1  coca-cola     94     NaN
2        NaN     57   pepsi
3        NaN     62   pepsi
4        NaN     70  orange
```

I want to fillna the object type with value in the corresponding columns.

Expected OUTPUT：

```
df
      company  price product
0  coca-cola     25    coca
1  coca-cola     94    coca
2  coca-cola     57   pepsi
3  coca-cola     62   pepsi
4  coca-cola     70  orange
```

I try as follows.

```
for col in df:
    #get dtype for column
    dt = df[col].dtype 
    #check if it is a number
    if dt == int or dt == float:
        pass
    else:
        df[col].fillna(df[col][0])
```

But `df[col][0]` maybe Nan,so I should fill a value that's not `nan`.
So how to do it?

Comment: Which column do you want to fill with? Can you post a desired output?

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Something like this `df['company'] = df['company'].fillna(df['product'])`?

Comment: So sorry for misleading U,and I have added my desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **`ffill`** and **`bfill`**

```
df.ffill().bfill()

  product  price    company
0    coca     25  coca-cola
1    coca     94  coca-cola
2   pepsi     57  coca-cola
3   pepsi     62  coca-cola
4  orange     70  coca-cola
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i in range(0,df.company.count()):
    if((df.company[i].isnull()==True)&(df.product[i].isnull()==False))
    df.company[i]=df.product[i]
    if((df.company[i].isnull()==False)&(df.product[i].isnull()==True))
    df.product[i]=df.company[i]
```

Or you can try this:

```
df['product'] = df['product'].fillna(df['company'])
df['company'] = df['company'].fillna(df['product'])
```